# Link to another page at an anchor point and also show div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have a single link that will take you to a different HTML page, down to a specific anchor tag, and also show a div that would be hidden by default.

I know how to link to another page and to an anchor on that page.

```
<a href="anotherpage.html#anchor5">Link</a>
```

On anotherpage.html, I have code to show that div.

```
<a onclick="toggle_visibility('hiddendiv');">Show div</a>
```

The Javascript for that is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
//-->
</script>
```

But I don't know how I could get the first link to also do what the second link is doing. Is this possible? This is for a local site, so I think I'm limited to just HTML, Javascript, and CSS.

Edit: I'm going to use this with Tipue Search (http://www.tipue.com/slide/). I'm going to have the search results point to specific sections on specific pages which have divs that are hidden by default. But in those sections, there are buttons to show those divs. I also included the Javascript I'm using for that above.

Comment: what if your user bookmarks the link with the anchor, would you still want the hidden div to appear ? if so, take a look to https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp

Answer (score 0):

The HTML page with the second link either has a `<script>` tag pointing to an external javascript file providing the `toggle_visiblility` function or that function is defined directly on the page.

If you add the function definition either by linking to the javascript file `<script src="myscripts.js"></script>` or copy the definition directly into a `<script>` tag.

Once the `toggle_visibility` function is available on your page, the first link can read simply `<a href="anotherpage.html#anchor5" onclick="toggle_visibility('hiddendiv');">Link</a>` , obviously replacing `hiddendiv` with the appropriate string.

Comment: I tried this. The link takes me to anotherpage.html#anchor5, but the div isn't made visible.

Comment: Help me understand your goal here: You click the first link, which goes to anotherpage.html#anchor5 . You're now on the second page. Do you want to hide a div on the second page, or a div on the page with the first link?

Comment: I want to have a link on one page (index.html) to go to anotherpage.html#anchor5 and unhide a div also on anotherpage.html. Does that make sense?

Comment: You'll need some way to pass a message to the anotherpage.html , such as a URL parameter, and then have additional code on anotherpage.html that processes your URL parameters and does something accordingly (in your case, that means hiding a div). So your `href` on the first link would be `anotherpage.html#anchor5&hidediv=hiddendiv` and then you would have code on anotherpage.html that runs on start, looks for a url param called `hidediv` and hides the div matching the given value. Here's one of many available tutorials on this topic https://davidwalsh.name/query-string-javascript

Answer (score 0):

can you please check this project at: https://github.com/nezirz/anchor_scroll

First page contains only link to second one:

```
<div>
    <a href="index2.html#anchor2"> go to index2 and show diw </a>
</div>
```

And second page contain this code:

```
<div>
    <div id="anchor1" style="background-color:blue; height:500px;">

    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div id="anchor2" style="background-color:green; height:400px;display: none;">

    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div id="anchor3" style="background-color:red; height:200px;">

    </div>
</div>
<script>
    window.onload = function() {

        var anchor =  window.location.hash.substr(1);
        console.log(anchor);
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            myFunction(anchor);
            Element.prototype.documentOffsetTop = function () {
                return this.offsetTop + ( this.offsetParent ? this.offsetParent.documentOffsetTop() : 0 );
            };

            var top = document.getElementById( anchor ).documentOffsetTop() - (window.innerHeight / 2 );
            window.scrollTo( 0, top );


         }, 2000);
         function myFunction(element) {
             console.log(element);
            var x = document.getElementById(element);
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
            }
    }

    };
</script>
```

This is only proof of concept, please update it to your exact requirement. I think that it is not complicated to you.